# How to create .exe executable file in Linux Ubuntu by .c source file

Tags: c, gcc, exe, executable

Suppose a programmer created a hello world program in c programming language in Linux, I know by gcc or cc command in terminal the input .c file is compiled to a.out, object file. But I want tk know is there any way to compile .c file to .exe file without using any IDE, on Linux only.

Comment: You mean a Windows exe?

Comment: Yes the windows .exe file format

Comment: @NimitBhardwaj: A simple so search or google search would have given you the answer. Anyways you are looking MingW or Cygwin or so..

Comment: Thx, my mistake, i didnt researched well thx and sorry